# Rebin irregularly gridded data to regular (2D) grid in Python, using mean/median

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a way to rebin irregularly gridded data onto a regular grid, but *without* interpolation (so not e.g. [`matplotlib.mlab.griddata`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.griddata). Preferably, I'd like to average or median the points within one cell, or even apply my own function.

The grid is 2D, but since I foresee future cases with different dimensions, an N-dimensional solution is even better.

As an example, consider the following data, with `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
data = np.arange(6)
x = np.array([0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.5, 1.8, 2.2])
y = np.array([0.4, 0.8, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7, 2.9])
```

which, when binned to a regular 3x3 grid and using average values, should result in:

```
[[ 0.5  nan  2. ]
 [ nan  nan  3.5]
 [ nan  nan  5. ]]
```

(NaN's are optional, but clearer than 0's, since the latter value can be an actual average; this is of course also easy to turn into a masked array.)

So far, I've been able to tackle the problem using Pandas:

```
xindices = np.digitize(x, np.arange(NX))
yindices = np.digitize(y, np.arange(NY))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': xindices,
    'y': yindices,
    'z': data
})
grouped = df.groupby(['y', 'x'])
result = grouped.aggregate(np.mean).reset_index()
grid = np.empty((NX, NY)) * np.NaN
grid[result['x']-1, result['y']-1] = result['z']
```

which allows me to pick any aggregating function I like.

However, since Pandas is rather general (Pandas doesn't care that `x` and `y` are grid indices), I feel that this may not be the optimal solution: having a solution that knows that the input and output are already on a (2D) grid seems more efficient. I have, however, not been able to find one; `np.digitize` comes closest, but that's only 1 dimensional, and still requires a loop in Python to access the indices and average or median over the data.

Does anyone know a better solution that the above one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

data = np.arange(6)
x = np.array([0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.5, 1.8, 2.2])
y = np.array([0.4, 0.8, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7, 2.9])

NX, NY = 4, 4
statistic, xedges, yedges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic_2d(
    x, y, values=data, statistic='mean', 
    bins=[np.arange(NX), np.arange(NY)])
print(statistic)
```

which yields

```
[[ 0.5  nan  2. ]
 [ nan  nan  3.5]
 [ nan  nan  5. ]]
```

There is also [`binned_statistic_dd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd.html) for higher dimensional binning.
Each of these functions support user-defined statistics by passing a callable to the `statistic` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for; must have missed it because of the "statistic" term, which I did not search for, thus ending up with interpolation variants. One thing: any idea why in the documentation, `x` and `values` have size `N`, while `y` has size `M`; somehow, that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think that is a bug in the documentation. They have to be the same size.